# Isn't that supposed to pick tls 1.3 by default in Android?

Tags: android, ssl, httpsurlconnection

According to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all, it says "In Android 10 and higher, TLS 1.3 is enabled by default for all TLS connections."

`javax.net.ssl.HttpsUrlConnection con = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsUrlConnection)new URL("myhttpsserverurl").openConnection();`

My https Server supports TLS 1.3 that I confirmed. I have Android 12 device.

I didn't explicitly use setSSLSocketFactory, which means I believe it uses "Default" one.

However, when I debugged the HttpsUrlConnection, it seems that it always picked TLS 1.2, not 1.3.

Is there anything I misunderstood?

I believe "Default" should pick the latest one available, which is TLS 1.3, because that is the latest one the server supports. If the server didn't support TLS 1.3, then it should pick 1.2 to continue...

Please let me know if I misunderstood something then.

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you get the information from that tks1.2 is used?

Comment: I used a tracer tool to check the version. BTW, if I use "Default", in this case, TLS 1.3 should be used. Isn't that correct anyway?

Comment: What tracer tool? For compatibility reasons TLS1.3 "lies" in the TLS client hello. A lot of tools don't know that and simply show TLS 1.2.

Comment: SSLContext.getDefault().getDefaultSSLparamegters().getProtocols() doesn't contain TLSv1.3, however, if I explicitly created SSLContext with TLSv1.3, then getProtocols() contains TLSv1.3...so I guess "Default" doesn't try to use 1.3... in order to use 1.3, I would have to explicitly create SSLContext instance...hum..then..doesn't make sense...the developer doc url indicates that TLS 1.3 is enabled by default...which means...SSLContext.getDefault().getDefaultSSLparamegters().getProtocols() should contain 1.3, but it obviously doesn't...... something I don't get it..hum..